# Click a button using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need my JavaScript file to click an asp button from another page, here is the code:

```
if (something..) {
            document.getElementById('<%=Button1(how to write it?).ClientID %>').click();
        }
```

Button1 is in the default.aspx file and the JavaScipt is in Click.aspx file - the javascript not in the default.aspx page
How can i do this action ?

This is my asp button:

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit confused with your question.

. If the button is in same page then you can do posback using

```
 __doPostBack(buttonID,'');
```

. if the button is in different page and that page isn't loaded. I don't think you can do the postback directly. May be you can pass parameter as query string and then on server side read the querystring and then if the value is there then fire button click event.

Edited

ASPX: default.aspx

```
    <script>
        var button1 = "<%= Button1.ClientID %>";
        var something = true;
    </script>
    <h3>We suggest the following:</h3>

   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return false;" OnClick="Button1_Click" />


    <script src="Scripts/test.js"></script>
```

JavaScript: test.js

```
var element = document.getElementById(button1);

if (element != null) {

    element.onclick = function () {
        if (!something) return false;
        return true;
    };
}
```

C#

```
 public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string a;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var clicked = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: that the issue, the javascript is in a different location file

Comment: you mean javascript is on different file not the aspx page?

Comment: Yes, :) thats the case .

Comment: Checked that, wrote it the same as you did, not working, in the default.aspx i have the button1, in the click.aspx i have the javascript, i did "if (something) {what you wrote..}"

Comment: @GiladAdar: Can you tell me what you actually want to do? The postback is a default feature of button. You are adding somecondition to have it postback? is it that you don't want the button to fire if the condition is not satisfied?

Comment: @GiladAdar: check the edited portion. Its working in my desktop

Answer (score 1):

JQuery allows you to do this pretty easily.

If you import JQuery into your project and then do this:

```
    $('buttonIdHere').click();
```

That should get you what you need.

Comment: @GiladAdar. This is javascript, and using jquery is the solution that will work on the most browsers and be the easiest to maintain. Don't forget ClientIDMode=Static.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your button's ID is Button1 and you want to cause the postback, use this in your javascript:

```
eval('<%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Button1, String.Empty) %>')
```

just noticed "JavaScript file to click an asp button from another page". what do you mean from another page?? You have page1.aspx with javascript on it and trying to call page2.aspx's button1?

if so, you won't be able to, cause there's no Page2 loaded. Use WebMethod instead:

1) In Page2 create a public static method doing whatever your Button1.Click callback does.

2) Replace Button1_Click with just the call to that static method.

3) then from javascript on your Page1 you can call PageMethods.YourMethodName

effectively executing the same routine as Button1_Click

**EDIT:**

example of how the end result might look:

```
Page2.aspx.cs

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyWebMethod();
}

[WebMethod]
public static void MyWebMethod ()
{
    //... Do something useful
}

Page1.aspx

<script>
    function callMyWebMethod(){
        PageMethods.MyWebMethod(function(){ // success callback}, function(){ // error callback});
    }
</script>
```

In order to have page methods work, you need a ScriptManager on the page with EnablePageMethods = True.

Comment: Nop, i ma getting : "CS0103: The name 'Button1' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Is it an asp:Button tag with an ID="Button1"?

Comment: where are you putting the eval command then? In markup or codebehind?

Comment: i did like this in the javascript: if (something) {
eval('<%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Button1, String.Empty) %>')
}

Comment: as a debugging tool, try create a function debug(){ alert($("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").attr("id")); } and call it. If it shows an alert with the full ID of the button

Comment: Ok, got it, how do i  "Replace Button1_Click with just the call to that static method" can you please give me example ?